# resignFirstResponder when UITextField on UIScrollView is not seen

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I have a `UITextField` on which I call `becomeFirstResponder` when I load the `ViewController`. On it, I have a `UIScrollView` and I would like to call `resignFirstResponder` on the `textField` when I have *scrolled it out* of my view.

The position of `UITextField` may change, but the behaviour should stay the same. Any ideas on how do you implement this sort of thing? Thanks.

Comment: Just for the record, the [objective-c] tag should really be reserved for questions relating to Objective-C lanugage usage or syntax. This question is more focussed on use of the Cocoa Touch library. Likewise, the [iphone] tag is inappropriate here, as it marks the question as being specific to iPhone, and excludes iPad. Pure pedrantry, I know :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at observing changes to your `scrollView`'s `contentOffset` property. With knowledge of `scrollView`'s `bounds` and `contentOffset`, and `textField`'s `frame` you could work out if `textField` is visible. Something like the following should work:

```
CGRect scrollViewVisibleBounds = CGRectOffset(scrollView.bounds, scrollView.contentsOffset.x, scrollView.contentsOffset.y);
BOOL textFieldIsVisible = CGRectIntersectsRect(textField.frame, scrollViewVisibleBounds);
```

The problem you have now is how to observe changes to `contentOffset`. It's not really feasible to be constantly observing (i.e. through KVO), as you'll receive multiple updates per second during, for example, a deceleration animation. I'd look at setting your `viewController` up as a [`UIScrollViewDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html) and updating your `textField`'s visibility via callbacks like `scrollViewDidEndDragging:` and `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating`.